# Background image on mobile

Tags: android, html, css

I've been trying to get the background image for a site to responsively stretch/crop whilst maintaining its aspect ratio; an affect I've achieved successfully using the below.

```css
body {
 background-image: url('image.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

When viewed on a desktop browser this works perfectly with the image adjusting to fit the change aspect ratio of the browser. However, when tested on a mobile (Chrome) the background image appears to ignore the "cover" value and returns to its original size (MASSIVE) and cuts straight off the side of the screen in both portrait and horizontal modes.

How can I get the mobile version to maintain it's size relative the the browser window and achieve the same behaviour I'm already getting for the desktop? Ideally CSS-fixes only please.

Thanks.

Comment: i think only way is using @media for smaller screens, your problems is made by fixed in my opinion

Answer (score -1):

`background-size: 100% 100%` (width height) should work.

Comment: I tried that but that then messes with the aspect ratio of the image so leaves it looking awful. :S

Comment: [www.scottychamsmusic.com](http://www.scottychamsmusic.com/)
Is this along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: No. See that is forcing the aspect ratio to change on the image, so it gets stretched and distorted. I'm looking for this: (look at background image from a desktop web browser - chrome is best - http://www.beckyspetservices.co.uk/ ). It works for this when viewed form desktop but when viewed on mobile the image doesn't scale properly and remains far too big.